# wrong url in ngx-translate when deploy on test

Tags: angular, url, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate in angular application that i am building and concat js files to be used in any other application but http request that get en.json file is wrong url it calls local files not test environment which is must be the current environment that I am working in it

i have followed the documentation of ngx-translate library but couldn't find any solution for this issue

[appModule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9FHX.png)

[appcomponent.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcAi0.png)

[in local works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loLhl.png)

[in test is wrong url and this is the main issue how to change the url to https://test......](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylx3a.png)

Comment: Please share example of your implementation and the error that you're seeing

Comment: i have edited the issue with images about my implementation and success case and fail case

Comment: is it clear enough for you @AhmadAlfy ?

Comment: Yes, I provided you with an answer

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot you posted, you are not running the application through an http server. You simple opened it as a file in your browser.

[image]

The file tries to retrieve the translation through a relative path and it's retrieved from the same protocol your application is served through.

You either need to run a local server (check out [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or any others you can find) or deploy your application to the cloud and it should work

Comment: yes you are right but this application will be injected to any other application so i have to set the url to be static url that get the translation files from my repo

Comment: @magdyelmansy this is a different problem. You're talking about an external service that serve as the translation source for multiple apps.

Comment: thank you for your answer that was the starting point to search in a right way and i found that i can inject static path for translation file and it will be called in all environments and fixed my issue  example is the solution above i have added solution for others how will search for this issue thank you again

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding the right path for my repo static in the configuration in app.module

[i18nPath in app module which I had added it in environment file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLXQc.png)